# If $ a + b = 4$, what is the value of $|4- a|+|4-b|$ ? ( $-4$ ? , $0$ ? , $4$ ? , $8$ ? , or impossible to determine? )

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, solution-verification, absolute-value

Source : CLEP COLLEGE ALGEBRA TEST 
http://www.nelnetsolutions.com/pdf/clep_collegealgebra_q_print.pdf

> If $ a + b = 4$, what is the value of $|4- a| +|4-b|$ ?  ( Possible
>   answers : $-4$ ? ,  $0$ ? , $4$ ? , $8$ ? ,  or impossible to
>   determine? )

I tried this

(1) If $ a + b = 4$ then

- $ a + b = |  a + b |$
- $a = 4 - b$

(2) So $|4- a| +|4-b| = | 4 - (4 - b)| + |4 - b| = |b| + |a|$

(3) By triangle inequality reversed : $|b| + |a| \geq |a+b|$ ( $= a+b$  , by (1) ).

(4) So $|4- a| +|4-b| \geq 4$.

Answer : impossible to determine.

Comment: Just try $a=10004$ and $b=-10000$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a+b = 4$, then $b = 4-a$ and $a = 4-b$, so $$|4-a|+|4-b| = |a|+|b|.$$
Now, if both $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, then $$|a|+|b| = a + b = 4.$$ However, it can also be the case that one of them is negative, WLOG, let it be $b$. Then, $a>4$ and $$|a|+|b| = a -b = a - (a-4) = 2a - 4 > 8 - 4 = 4.$$ We conclude that $|4-a|+|4-b|$ can obtain any value greater or equal than $4$, and thus is impossible to determine from the given data.

Comment: Actually I didn't consider the two cases ( positive / one negaative). Does it invalidate the proof I attempted? ( Just for information).

Comment: @Ray LittleRock, it looks to me that everything you wrote is correct. However, from that it does not follow that the expression can obtain more than one value.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to determine. Just try a couple different examples. $(a,b)=(4,0), (-1,5)$ should give you different results

Comment: Sorry, do you mean my reasoning went wrong somewhere? Or that the answer is obvious by inspecting some example?

Comment: @RayLittleRock that the answer is obvious by inspecting some example, in particular when $|a|$ and $|b|$ are large like HagenvonEitzen's example above in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $b = 4 - a$, we can draw a graph of $|4-a| + |4-(4-a)|$ to see what happens.

If we [enter the formula on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C4%20-%20a%7C%20%2B%20%7C4%20-%20%284%20-%20a%29%7C), we get the following graph:

[image: graph]

Since $|4 - (4 - a)| = |a|$, the formula is equal to $|4 - a| + |a|$, which can be interpreted as *distance to 4* + *distance to 0*.